# The correct use of "in the manner"

Tags: phrase-usage

Please help me construct the correct sentence?

should I say: *In the manner of a;*

> I decided to wake-up at this moment and begin to end its existence *in the manner of a* true permanent death, denying it the rest of its life.

Or should it be: *In the manner of;*

> I decided to wake-up at this moment and begin to end its existence *in the manner of* true permanent death, denying it the rest of its life.

True permanent death is a specific action and not among many actions possible i.e. there is only one way to kill someone/something.

Comment: The adverbial phrase *in the manner of* is a somewhat dated "literary / poetic" usage, but it doesn't really work in your context anyway. The basic form *to [verb] in the manner of Y* normally means to ***imitate** Y* (to carry out the action indicated by *[verb]* in the same way that *Y* would do it). I must admit I'm not clear exactly what your example text is supposed to mean (it seems to be a rather obscure/bizarre context), but I suggest you discard all that inappropriate verbiage and replace it with plain ***by*** or ***with***, for example.

Comment: Note that the phrasal verb ***wake up*** (= intransitive ***to awaken*** and transitive ***to wake** [someone else]*) is always written as two words. The hyphenated form only occurs as an adjectival usage. For example, a hotel might give you a "literal" ***wake-up call*** in the morning, and this particular form is often used metaphorically in political / social contexts.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Thank you for mentioning the correct use of wake up. I agree the context of my sentence is very abstract, that's why I need help.

Comment: @Guygar what is "it" in this sentence?  What are you killing?  I suspect there is a better metaphor available in English, but I need more information.

Comment: @Andrew: In this case "it" is something. For example, if you hit an atom so hard that instead of releasing energy it completely ceases to exist.

Comment: @Guygar actually that's not what happens to the atom, but that's beside the point.  Did you have something specific in mind here?  It's hard to imagine waking up in the morning determined to kill something as trivial as an *atom*, so I'm still a little confused what you are trying to say.

Comment: @Andrew: Yes I know that about atoms. It was just an attempt at establishing a little bit of clarity. It is possible to perceive that instead of energy transference, something can be destroyed completely so that it no longer exists. A complete death of something.

Comment: What does "its" refer to?

Comment: @Lambie: "its existence", "its life". "It" is any kind of matter that exists. It impossible to express clearly without quoting my paper and that has consequences i.e. I might get marked down for sharing my ideas before submission. Thanks.

Comment: To me, in your context "its" does not mean much in this sentence: I decided to wake-up at this moment and **begin to end its existence**. You were beginning to end the existence of what? [the fly on the wall; the fantasy plaguing you;the skunk living in your yard??]. It seems most curious to me [as seen in Alice in Wonderland phrase].

Comment: In the manner of means: in the style of, often written as; à la x, in English. I don't understand how one can end the existence of some thing in the manner of some other thing except in a very specific context such as: "He ended the fly's existence in the manner of the execution of Louis the 16th". –

Comment: @Lambie: Thank you, this is helpful. For example, let's say we could kill something like so; simple zap: turns the matter into some other matter. serious zap: the matter in question is completely destroyed i.e. it is gone from everywhere. So I want to say in my sentence that I am killing something using a serious zap. Makes sense? Thanks.

Comment: In that case, in the manner of is probably not appropriate to your goal. There are many fine verbs in English: to pulverize;to exterminate, etc.

Comment: @Lambie: Is this sentence better? (I decided to wake up at this moment and began to end its existence ensuring a true permanent death, denying it the rest of its life.

Comment: wake up at ***that*** moment [you are telling the story in the past]. Yes, it makes more sense now.

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence is confusing because you use the neutral pronoun "it", which in English is used to describe *things*.  Unless you're talking about some kind of living being (like an animal or plant), things don't have a life to end.  We can talk metaphorically about ending the life of something like a *rock*, but without the proper context it can sound bizarre.

Assuming the proper context where you explain the "life" of this inanimate *it*, then "in the manner of (a) permanent death" makes a kind of sense with or without the "a".  Still, "permanent death" is a meaningless phrase.  When is *death* not *permanent*?  And how is action that works *in the manner of* ending something's existence any different from simply ending its existence?

My point is that I suspect you're trying to force a direct translation from your native language into English, but the words you choose do not carry the same meaning or nuance.  As FumbleFingers says in his comment, acting "in the manner of" something means to *imitate* that thing -- but if you end something's existence then there is no *imitation* about it.  It's either *dead* or *not dead*.  There is no in-between (except perhaps in metaphysics, but that's a different topic).

I hope you can appreciate our confusion.  Nevertheless, as an attempt to answer your question:

When talking about "completely ending something's existence" it would be better (or at least more *elegant*) to use available vocabulary that leaves no doubt in the reader's mind what you mean:

> - annihilate
> - obliterate

and possibly (depending on context):

> - destroy
> - eliminate
> - eradicate
> - liquidate
> - extinguish
> - extirpate
> - exterminate
> - wipe out

and others.  English has a great many words that refer to *getting rid* of things.

Much depends on what "it" is in your example sentence.  You can *annihilate* a particle of matter, you can *eliminate* a pestilent bacterium, you can *liquidate* an asset, you can *obliterate* any reference to a historical event, and so on.

Suppose you are writing a philosophical/religious tract, and in this case "it" is the egotistical attachment to the material world, which various beliefs say is the root of existential suffering.  You might then want to say that you woke up one day with the desire to *eradicate* this attachment -- which is to say, to *completely remove* it from its place in your psyche.  Other possible verbs:  *expunge, purge, expurgate, extirpate, expel, purify, eliminate,* and various others.

Or suppose you are talking about the paranormal, and the thing you want to end the existence of is a *ghost* that has been *haunting* your house.  In this case English has the wonderfully specific verb *exorcise*, which means "to drive out an evil spirit".

Anyway, these are just some random examples that (more or less) fit your context.  If you want to provide more specifics, I could probably write a more useful answer.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution in the matter. The paper is indeed an essay based on metaphysical issues and that's why I am having some problems expressing myself. Sorry for the ambiguity. The use of "manner" in this case is completely wrong. I have restructured the sentence now and I believe it works.

Answer (score -1):

Both of them work, however, I believe that "in the matter of a" sounds much better and puts better emphasise on the "true permanent death"

Adding the **a** implies that it *is* a true permanent death, whereas without it, the sentence structure is the same as sentence used to *compare* to the death, rather than being one

Comment: I am not sure why this is downvoted. An explanation would help.

Comment: It was my downvote, on the grounds that ***in the manner of*** and ***in the matter of***  have no real semantic connection. Just because OP is being so doggedly vague about *exactly* what he's trying to say doesn't justify proposing an alternative based purely on the fact of changing a letter or two.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Thank you. Your tips really helped a lot.